# My android application not read image from USB in android 6.0 and above versions

Tags: android

I have given permissions in Android manifest as well as runtime permission where user can provide permission for storage. Storage permission also enables for my application.
But it failed to read image from usb, sd card in android 6.0 and above version devices.

It works perfectly in android 4.4 and 5.1.

I don't know why it is not work so in android 6 and above.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try adding   `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside Application in Manifest file

Comment: Hi. I tried it but it shows, no attribute found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that issue. In my code I have read image from path "/mnt". But in above Android 6.0 , path start as "/storage". So i changed my path from "/mnt" to "/storage". Now my app read image from sdcard/usb.

Hope it will help someone.

Thank you.